# how can I use youtube API to search channels by country?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube.net-api

I want to search Youtube channels and filter them by the user's country among other stuff 
How can i do that ?

I never dealt with an API before , so it would be useful to direct me which language should I use and some tutorials on youtube APIs other than Google's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the api in different languages , you should go through developers API here , It has all details,

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

Search for standard feeds here ,

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

search appropriate URL according to your needs.